# Python - Different logs should be in different files, but appear on the same file

Tags: python, apache, logging, falconframework

I have a web application, with a minimal logging functionality. The backend runs on Apache with Falcon (on Python).

Each request has the following code

```
msg = 'user: {usr} running {req} {req_uri:<30} | from: {loc_ip}:{loc_port} '.format(
        usr=req.env['REMOTE_USER'],
        req=req.env['REQUEST_METHOD'],
        loc_ip=req.env['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        loc_port=req.env['REMOTE_PORT'],
        req_uri=req.env['REQUEST_URI'])

    log_name = 'logs/{remote_ip}/{remote_ip}_{day}.log'.format(remote_ip=req.env['REMOTE_ADDR'], day=datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime('%d_%m_%Y'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(log_name), exist_ok=True)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_name, level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s - [%(module)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s', datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    logging.info(msg)
```

And I access the app from 2 different IPs (IPx, and IPy) - so there should be 2 folder under 'logs', folder 'IPx' and folder 'IPy', with a log file in each..

But after I access the web, I see 2 folders, but only one of the folders has a log file inside (lets say IPx_day.log in IPx folder), but after reviewing the IPx_day.log file I see:

```
[TIME] - INFO - [FILE] user: user1 running GET /domain | from: IPy:PORTy
// Other log statments..
[TIME] - INFO - [FILE] user: user2 running GET /domain | from: IPx:PORTx
```

both lines are in the file file - IPx_day.log

Has anyone have idea why both lines appear in the same file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I would add this as a comment but I don't have the reputation to do so.]

I think it might have something to do with logging.basicConfig() which only configures the root logger. I think you'd have to use multiple loggers or better just attach multiple handlers to one logger.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig
https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html

Answer (score 1):

From your writing, what I have understood is

1. You're creating 2 different folders and the log file in respective
   directories.
2. You run a app from IPx, and you see logs in IPx.log but
       when you run app from IPy, logs for IPy are in IPx.log.

If that is right, can you please check if

1. Right IP[remote_IP] is being passed all the time?
2. Print the IP and log_name and check what IP you're getting and the the log directory.

I presume, a path change is required. Unless you're in the base path[source of the script]